# Turn array of unique strings into nested object

Tags: javascript

I have a special type of number system being used and want to change the data structure into an object to help with the data reading part.

Basically I want to turn:

```js
const myArray = ["1", "1.2.3.4", "1.2.3", "1.2", "2", "2.1"]
```

Into:

```js
{
 1: { 
   id: "1", 
   child: { 
     id: "1.2", 
     child: { 
       id: "1.2.3", 
       child: { 
         id: "1.2.3.4", 
         child: null 
     } 
   } 
 }, 
 2: { id: "2", child: { id: "2.1", child: null } }
}
```

I know I need to use a recursive function, and probably split on the strings to get the values, but for some reason I can't put it together in my head. Something along the lines of mapping and passing the next obj in line to the function I think.

Comment: Post the JS you've already tried and failed with and we'll fix it for you. See how to post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to do this in two passes with the first pass just to arrange the data into an object that has keys corresponding with the first number of each item in the array. During this pass you could also store all the relevant items for sorting

```
const arranged = {};
myArray.forEach((item) => {
    let key = item.split(".")[0];
    let items = (arranged[key] && arranged[key].items) ? [...arranged[key].items, item] : [item];
    arranged[key] = {id:key.toString(), items:items.sort()}
});
```

Then do a second pass on the arranged object to create a new object with the same keys but do the recursion on the previously stored items so at least they'll be in the right order

```
const result = {};
const buildResult = (items, current) => {
    if(current === (items.length - 1)) {return {id:items[current], child:undefined}}
    return {id:items[current], child:buildResult(items, (current + 1))}
}
Object.keys(arranged).forEach((key) => {
    result[key] = buildResult(arranged[key].items, 0);
});
```

I've had to make a lot of assumptions here and I wouldn't consider this to be very efficient for larger data sets but maybe it can help you get closer to a better solution, here's a jsfiddle as an example

https://jsfiddle.net/2uqgy6kw/1/

Comment: Great starting point, I think I can take it from here! This does work though, so I'm going to accept it for now! Thanks :)